# php - auto prefixing css with php

Tags: php, css, autoprefixer

I am building a php application which is automatically generating css stylesheet and I need it to be able to generate cross browser compatible css properties.

I found that `autoprefixer` do it, but it require Nodejs installation on user's server.

Is there a php class which don't require additional software installation on user's server?

Comment: lets see your code for creating the CSS document!

Comment: I am doing php file read and write and use this php class https://github.com/webdev20/cssparserclass to generate the css with php. But this not about the error in my code, but the availability of css auto prefixer built with php, just like autoprefixer but don't require Nodejs installation on the server.

Comment: Have you found it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody has started on this, here:
https://github.com/adamdodev/autoprefixer-php-native

However it's still in alpha version and currently says:

> *Work in Progress - Doesn't in any way work. If you stumble across this and like the idea, send me a message.*

But other than that, I have not yet found a fully-PHP version of a CSS auto-prefixer.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed CSS autoprefixer in pure PHP. So I tried to make it.

You can use it and contribute it

https://github.com/padaliyajay/php-autoprefixer